# Browser.GetRemoteDebuggingURL() of DotNetBrowser returns string.Empty

Tags: c#, winforms, dotnetbrowser

I set up an Winform-Application (in future it will be WPF) with the `DotNetBrowserControl`

```
BrowserView browserView = new 
    WinFormsBrowserView(BrowserFactory.Create(BrowserType.HEAVYWEIGHT));
Controls.Add((Control)m_BrowserView);
string remoteDebuggingUrl = m_BrowserView.Browser.GetRemoteDebuggingURL();
```

notice that `remoteDebuggingUrl` is `string.Empty`

DotNetBrowserVersion/DotNetBrowserChromium - Version:1.8.3.0
.NetFramework: 4.5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks stuartd,

this is exactly what needs to be done.

But in fact I gathered out my fault.

`BrowserPreferences.SetChromiumSwitches("--remote-debugging-port=9222")`

see http://dotnetbrowser-support.teamdev.com/documentation/chromium-switches

here you see, that `SetChromiumSwitches` takes whether a string, or a string params array

my switch string has been like this `"--switchOne --switchTwo"`, 
so it's only a string and not an array.

The problem in general is, that it worked like this in earlier days.
As I now switched to a `string[]` it works fine

Answer (score 5):

From the [documentation](http://dotnetbrowser-support.teamdev.com/documentation/remote-debugging):

> DotNetBrowser provides functionality that allows you to use the Chrome Developer Tools remote debugging feature. **To enable this feature you must define the remote-debugging-port Chromium switch by calling the BrowserPreferences.SetChromiumSwitches(String...) method before creating any Browser instance.**
>
> Once you configured DotNetBrowser to use a specified remote debugging port, you can get a remote DevTools URL by calling the Browser.GetRemoteDebuggingURL() method:
>
> Sample:

```
BrowserPreferences.SetChromiumSwitches("--remote-debugging-port=9222");
InitializeComponent();
browserView.Browser.LoadURL("http://www.google.com");
string remoteDebuggingURL = browserView.Browser.GetRemoteDebuggingURL();
```